# Pie Chart With Export PDF Highchart Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pdf-generation

When I export a PDF with this pie chart some times it's working and some times not. It's like an below image.

[image]

This is a code for generate pie chart.
obj data is fine.

```
    $(".curve_chart").each(function () {
        var dataXAxis = [];
        var length = 0;
        length = obj.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dataXAxis.push({name: obj[i].label, y: obj[i].y});
        }
        $('#curve_chart_' + que_id).highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: que_txt,
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y} ',
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    name: "names",
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: dataXAxis
                }]
        });
    });
});
```

Please help me for the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please please reply if anyone is there.
It's very important for me.

Comment: tried many times,exported the chart of fiddle .always working fine for me.

Comment: We need to stable demo which allows us to recreate issue. Unfortuantely "sometimes is wrong" is not very helpful.